# Can multiple users work directly on a NAS

Tags: vpn, network-share, network-attached-storage, file-server

The title may be confusing but I'll try to explain my question the best I can.

Say I have two physical offices, on one I have all my data (excel files, word files, pdf's, etc). On the other I have my computer, without any data.

I want to access all my data and work on my files through the web, without any of the files being on my physical PC.

Is it possible to do this, and can I do this with multiple users at the time working on different files?

Answer (score 0):

VPNs are very good at this. Launch a vpn server where the data is (either location will work though), then connect a vpn client on your computer. That will give you a secure route/access to the other location.

Most NAS systems have support for VPNs by default.

Comment: Yes, but can I and other users access different data at the same time?

Comment: Absolutely, you give your users a vpn profile with their own user. Each user can access any data that they are allowed to concurrently.